# How to add directory to class path in ubuntu?

Tags: java, oop, package

Suppose i have a directory "Animal" (without quotes) and i have java classes in it.How to add that directory to class path in Linux ? I mean suppose i want to use class files in "Animal" directory from some other folder , then i need to add "Animal" to class path .How to do it ?

Also suppose Animal directory has several sub directories and each of the sub directories also have directory having java class files .Then how to add each of them to java package ?

edit : Suppose i have two folders in Ubuntu say Downloads and Documents .Now in Downloads i created a folder called "animal" having a class named Dog.java .  Now in Documents folder i created main method in which i try to make an instance of "Dog" class .I want to do it by importing the package "animal" in Download folder. How to do it ?We know that if we want to use some pre-built package in java then we import that package to use classes inside that package .Similarly suppose i want to import my own package , what i need to do ? When i write import and compile then it says package "animal" does not exist .So what i do so that it doesn't gives compilation error .Can some one elaborate by giving an answer .

I did lot of work before asking this question and when i was unsuccessful i finally asked this question .

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: @jrook I visited it before , how do it with terminal .I am not able to understand

Comment: You should call `java -cp animal:anotherFolder:etc your.main.ClassName` . Folder names are separated by `:`. The "plain" way to invoke java is `java MyClass`, and that will call the `main` method in the class you specify. The `-cp`  option lets you add folders to the class path. Folder names can be relative (to the working folder you run `java` from) or absolute

Comment: check https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/environment_variables.html

Comment: @Daniele How to add my folder or package in class path such that when i use import statement from some other directory it is identified what i am saying ?

Comment: @HarryWilliamson, they already answered, though - classpath is a runtime artifact, not related to `import` statements. Seems like you are asking about something else entirely. Please add a [mcve] into your question.

Comment: Suppose you have a class `com.sample.package.MainClass`. In order to run this class, let say you have the folder structure: `classes/com/sample/package/MainClass.class`. Then in order to run its main method, `cd` into the parent folder of `classes` and call `java -cp classes com.sample.package.MainClass` .

Comment: @Daniele can i use some sort of export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/servlet-api.jar command here ? what will be the correct syntax for adding "Animal" to class path .

Comment: You can use `-cp .:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/servlet-api.jar` , or `-cp .:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/*` . (setting the CLASSPATH env variable should work too- but I usually prefer the `-cp` option)

Comment: @Daniele i have elaborated my question more , please check once .

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I have elaborated my question more , please check once

Comment: @Daniele Please just last time help me

Comment: sure :), see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work this out in detail, with some code- the folder structure is:

```
~ (user folder)
~/Documents
~/Documents/useanimal
~/Documents/useanimal/UseDog.java
~/Downloads
~/Downloads/animal
~/Downloads/animal/Dog.java
```

The code for the two classes is below. To compile:

```
cd ~/Downloads
javac animal/Dog.java
cd ~/Documents
javac -cp ~/Downloads useanimal/UseDog.java
```

To run:

```
cd ~
java -cp Documents:Downloads useanimal.UseDog
```

and it will output

```
UseDog:main
Dog created
```

---

Code:

**animal/Dog.java**

```
package animal;

public class Dog {
  public Dog() {
    System.out.println("Dog created");
  }
}
```

**useanimal/UseDog.java**

```
package useanimal;
import animal.Dog;

public class UseDog {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("UseDog:main");
    Dog dog = new Dog();  
  }
}
```